# scapy send packet getting RST

Tags: scapy, packet-capture

The iptables are stopped, whenever i tried to send packet with scapy i'm getting the packet is getting

> RST after SYN/ACK

**the iptables are stopped,**

the packet are send from MACOSX to Linux OS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably an RST packet sent by the MacOS IP stack.

1. Scapy (on the MacOS computer) sends a TCP SYN packet.
2. The IP stack of the Linux computer sends a TCP SYN-ACK packet (the port is open).
3. The IP stack of the MacOS computer receives the TCP SYN-ACK packet while it has not sent a matching TCP SYN packet. It sends a RST packet, as it is supposed to do.

You can use a firewall on the MacOS computer to prevent the IP stack from getting the SYN-ACK packet.